# Using group_by() function on multiple data frames?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that were collected from a year but are broken up by months. For my code, I labeled them df1-df12 for each corresponding month. I am trying to group these data using the group_by function to group all the dataframes similarly. When I do the following code- it works fine alone:

```
  df <- df %>%
  group_by(date,id) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However, I would like to streamline this code so that I can use this function for all 12 dataframes without having to copy/paste 12 times, since there is a lot of data to go through. Here is what I have tried to do to that end:

```
func1<-function(df)
  {
  df <- df %>%
  group_by(date,id) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup()
  }
yr19<-c(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12)
map(yr19, func1)
```

However, i get the following error message:  Error in UseMethod("group_by") :
no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "character". As stated above- i don't get this error message if I go through and do it individually, but there are many months and many years to be analyzed and from a time perspective I don't think doing this code manually is feasible. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `yr19 <- list(df1, df2, ...`

Comment: Also, you might need to return `df` at the end of your function, or remove the assigning `df <-`  at the beginning of your function body.

Comment: As an alternative, you might consider combining your data frames and coding the month and year as variables.  Then you can `group_by(year, month, date, id)` and run the rest of your code once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you can approach this, first using the approach suggested by @ktiu:

```
## Create example data
library(dplyr)  # for pipe and group_by()

set.seed(914)
df1 <- tibble(
      date = sample(1:30, 50, replace = T),
      id = sample(1:10, 50, replace = T),
      var1 = rnorm(50, mean = 10, sd = 3)
)

df2 <- tibble(
      date = sample(1:30, 50, replace = T),
      id = sample(1:10, 50, replace = T),
      var1 = rnorm(50, mean = 10, sd = 3)
)
```

Modifying your function to address error

```
func1<-function(df)
{
      df <- df %>%
            group_by(date,id) %>%
            slice(n()) %>%
            ungroup()
      df
}

## And using list rather than c to combine data frames.
yr19 <- list(df1, df2)
yr19_data <- lapply(yr19, func1)

# This will return a list of data frames you can access with `yr19_data[[1]]`
```

Alternative approach is to add variable for your source data frames, then collapse it all into a single data frame and manipulate from there.  Which approach makes more sense will depend on what else you want to do later.

```
func2 <- function(df.name){
      mutate(get(df.name), source = df.name)
}
# This is set up to get objects given their names, so we'll use a character vector
# of names to iterate off of. 
yr19 = c("df1", "df2")
df.list <- lapply(yr19, func2)
df.long <- do.call(bind_rows, df.list)
df.long
# # A tibble: 100 x 4
# date    id  var1 source
# <int> <int> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1    27     9  9.31 df1   
# 2     5     3 16.5  df1   
# 3    28     3  2.67 df1   
# 4    24     4  8.94 df1   
# 5    13     3  1.68 df1
```

At this point you can manipulate one data frame in your original pipe:

```
df <- df.long %>%
      group_by(source, date,id) %>%
      slice(n()) %>%
      ungroup()
df

# # A tibble: 93 x 4
# date    id  var1 source
# <int> <int> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1     1     8  9.89 df1   
# 2     2     4 10.9  df1   
# 3     4     3  8.45 df1   
# 4     5     3 16.5  df1   
# 5     5     7 10.6  df1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate both of your help! I ended up using the first method only because we are interested in looking at month-level data and the data collected (columns) vary across some of the months! Thank you for a clear answer, I'm new to using R in a higher-throughput manner so loops and making functions is new to me!